# distinct with multiple fields and with where condition in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to write a query equivalent to `distinct` and `where` in `mongodb`. the sql query is  `select DISTINCT key,score from GPC where note="test2" and notetwo = "meet2"`

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4dc86fef6a0aa8513ab5f21c"), "key" : "SAGAR","score" : 16, "note" : "test1", "notetwo" : "meet1" } 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4dc86ffd6a0aa8513ab5f21d"), "key" : "SAGAR456", "score" : 17, "note" : "testjh1", "notetwo" : "meetjh1" } 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4dc8700b6a0aa8513ab5f21e"), "key" : "SAGAR33", "score" : 37, "note" : "test2", "notetwo" : "meet2" } 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4dc871686a0aa8513ab5f21f"), "key" : "SAGAR33", "score" : 37, "note" : "test2", "notetwo" : "meet2" } 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4dc871696a0aa8513ab5f220"), "key" : "SAGAR33", "score" : 37, "note" : "test2", "notetwo" : "meet2" } 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4dc8716c6a0aa8513ab5f221"), "key" : "SAGAR456", "score" : 17, "note" : "testjh1", "notetwo" : "meetjh1" }
```

Expected result from the query is

> [{"key" : "SAGAR33", "score" : 37}]

What is the equivalent query in `mongodb`. I am using mongoose to execute queries.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You'll need to use the [`aggregate`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) queries for achieving this.  Here's an example that will work in shell (which can be translated to Mongoose easily):

```js
db.gpc.aggregate([
    // your where clause: note="test2" and notetwo = "meet2"
    {"$match" : {note:"test2", notetwo:"meet2"}}, 
    // group by key, score to get distinct
    {"$group" : {_id : {key:"$key", score:"$score"}}}, 
    // Clean up the output
    {"$project" : {_id:0, key:"$_id.key", score:"$_id.score"}}
])
```

Output:

```js
{ "result" : [ { "key" : "SAGAR33", "score" : 37 } ], "ok" : 1 }
```