# Getting Distinct values of multiple values in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, bson

Let's imagine I have the following collection of books (Edited out the ID field for compactness):

```
{ "author" : "Steve Jones", "title" : "Fun Stuff",    "edition" : "2010" }
{ "author" : "Steve Jones", "title" : "Fun Stuff",    "edition" : "2011" }
{ "author" : "Steve Jones", "title" : "Boring Stuff", "edition" : "2010" }
{ "author" : "Ben Johnson", "title" : "Other Stuff",  "edition" : "2010" }
```

What should I do I want to find only the latest edition of each book? In other words: I want to get a result which omits the 2010 edition of Steve Jones' *Fun Stuff*, and only has the 2011 edition:

```
{ "author" : "Steve Jones", "title" : "Fun Stuff",    "edition" : "2011" }
{ "author" : "Steve Jones", "title" : "Boring Stuff", "edition" : "2010" }
{ "author" : "Ben Johnson", "title" : "Other Stuff",  "edition" : "2010" }
```

If this was a relational database and I were writing a query, I'd probably write something like `SELECT DISTINCT title, DISTINCT author, edition WHERE 1 SORT BY edition DESC`. So my instinct coming from a SQL background is to look up [db.collection.distinct()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) but it seems to work pretty differently than what I'm used to; it only returns an array with each distinct value for that a single field.

Is this something that I would need to tackle programmatically? Or can I do this entirely with mongo functions and bson?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119692/distinct-with-multiple-fields-and-with-where-condition-in-mongodb maybe check this for reference?

Comment: Oh hey, look at me, asking questions that have already been answered.  It's not the *exact* same type of question, but it had what I was looking for nonetheless. Thanks @Shih-MinLee.

Comment: no prob man glad it helps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this to start:

```
db.textbooks.aggregate({ $group: {
    _id: { title: "$title", author: "$author" },
    latestEdition: { $max: "$edition" }
}})
```

That will give you each unique book by title & author and the latest edition. Play around with the query and [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/aggregation-introduction/) to get exactly what you want.