# NodeJs is sending empty response

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using NodeJS and MongoDb as a backend service.I am trying to retrieve distinct data based on condition like I want to get names where order status is pending:

```
const coll = client.db("My_db").collection("Orders");
            coll.distinct("name",{order_status:"pending"},(function(err,docs){

                  let output = docs.map(r => ({'name':r.name}));
                  res.send(output);       

            }));
```

But it is sending empty array like this:

```
[
 {},
 {},
 {},
 {},
 {},
 {}
]
```

Someone please let me know what I am doing wrong.Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: can you try to console.log the output variable ?

Comment: On doing `console.log()` its showing `{name:undefined}`

Comment: Are you positive you're showing us the correct route handler? Can you try `res.send("test");` instead to make sure? Because I don't see how the above code could result in the response you posted.

Comment: Everything is correct I got the solution thw problem was in `r.name` i need to use only `r`.Now it is showing proper names.

Comment: Print out `docs` object with `console.log(docs);`. let's check error first.

Comment: This issue has been resolved now  problem was in `r.name`

Comment: Now tell me how can I get phone along with name

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation [Distinct Mongo DB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#specify-query-with-distinct)

Thay result will be array .But you are matching `r.name` its a object key .

So do with argument only

```
let output = docs.map(r => ({'name':r}));
```

Comment: What if i want to get phone number along with name.

Comment: you could do with [`aggregation group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32194449/getting-distinct-values-of-multiple-values-in-mongodb)  .Still i m also learning mongo db

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run map over that response. The distinct function returns the array of distinct values. Try console.log(docs) and check it

Answer (score 0):

Because you have specified field as name, you don't need to use r.name, just use r

You can refer to the [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/), hope this will help you :)

If your MongoDB is above 2.2 and you want to find multiple fields, you can use aggregate

```
collection = db.tb;
collection.aggregate([
  {"$group": { "_id": { name: "$name", email: "$email" } } }
]);
```